# What part of an x509 certificate should I store in the database to look up a user?

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

I have a web application that uses Forms Auth against a custom user store. We want to extend our Users entity so we can configure a client certificate to use in lieu of username/password.

I have successfully configured IIS to accept client certificates, and I can inspect the client certificate in my security module's `AuthorizeRequest` event and validate it. The final step is to be able to associate the provided client certificate with a user. For testing purposes, I am currently recording a certificate's subject name in my Users table, and looking up a user that way.

Of course, that isn't adequate for production. What should I store in my Users table from the client certificate so I can look up and log the user in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the certificate's thumbprint as the key for storing or looking up the certificate, or for looking up the user given the certificate.  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint.aspx